# Laravel Excel - Access variable outside function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I am using http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs and I am trying to access a variable outside of this function. I read about globals but it seems like a poor solution.

```
Excel::load($request->file, function ($results) {
    foreach ($results->toArray() as $row) {
       $rows[] = $row;
    }
});
```

Further down in my script I would like to access `$rows` outside of the above function. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
$results = Excel::load($request->file);
$data = $results->toArray();
```

Was able to remove the function and still modify and access the data that I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare $rows as array
 `$rows=[];` before and outside of closure function. You also need to have `use($rows)` in your closure.

```
Excel::load($request->file, function ($results) use($rows) {
foreach ($results->toArray() as $row) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}
```

});

otherwise there can be other method like

```
      $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
        $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
        })->get();

        dd($data);
```